KeyError: 'DEFAULT' when attempting to create a table using magic line %sql in Jupyter Notebook
I am attempting to create a new database and create a table using magic line %sql in Jupyter Notebook but I've been getting a KeyError and I'm struggling to work out why, my code is as follows.
import sqlite3 as sql
import pandas as pd

%load_ext sql

%sql sqlite:///dataProgramming.db

%%sql sqlite://
CREATE TABLE
  users (
    FirstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    USERID INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (USERID)
  );

When I run this I get the following traceback.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('sql', 'sqlite://', 'CREATE TABLE\n  users (\n    FirstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,\n    LastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,\n    USERID INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n    PRIMARY KEY (USERID)\n  );\n')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2541, in InteractiveShell.run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2539 with self.builtin_trap:
   2540     args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2541     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2543 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2544 # when using magics with decorator @output_can_be_silenced
   2545 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2546 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sql\magic.py:365, in SqlMagic.execute(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    257 @no_var_expand
    258 @needs_local_scope
    259 @line_magic("sql")
   (...)
    337 )
    338 def execute(self, line="", cell="", local_ns=None):
    339     """
    340     Runs SQL statement against a database, specified by
    341     SQLAlchemy connect string.
   (...)
    363 
    364     """
--> 365     return self._execute(
    366         line=line, cell=cell, local_ns=local_ns, is_interactive_mode=False
    367     )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ploomber_core\exceptions.py:128, in modify_exceptions.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    125 @wraps(fn)
    126 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    127     try:
--> 128         return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    129     except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
    130         _add_community_link(e)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sql\magic.py:624, in SqlMagic._execute(self, line, cell, local_ns, is_interactive_mode)
    621     handle_exception(e, command.sql, self.short_errors)
    622 except Exception as e:
    623     # Handle non SQLAlchemy errors
--> 624     handle_exception(e, command.sql, self.short_errors)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sql\error_handler.py:115, in handle_exception(error, query, short_error)
    113         _display_error_msg_with_trace(error, detailed_message)
    114 else:
--> 115     raise error

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sql\magic.py:578, in SqlMagic._execute(self, line, cell, local_ns, is_interactive_mode)
    575     parameters = user_ns
    577 try:
--> 578     result = run_statements(conn, command.sql, self, parameters=parameters)
    580     if (
    581         result is not None
    582         and not isinstance(result, str)
   (...)
    585         # Instead of returning values, set variables directly in the
    586         # users namespace. Variable names given by column names
    588         if self.autopandas or self.autopolars:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sql\run\run.py:65, in run_statements(conn, sql, config, parameters)
     58         if (
     59             config.feedback >= 1
     60             and hasattr(result, "rowcount")
     61             and result.rowcount > 0
     62         ):
     63             display.message_success(f"{result.rowcount} rows affected.")
---> 65 result_set = ResultSet(result, config, statement, conn)
     66 return select_df_type(result_set, config)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sql\run\resultset.py:39, in ResultSet.__init__(self, sqlaproxy, config, statement, conn)
     36 self._is_dbapi_results = hasattr(sqlaproxy, "description")
     38 # note that calling this will fetch the keys
---> 39 self._pretty_table = self._init_table()
     41 self._mark_fetching_as_done = False
     43 if self._config.autolimit == 1:
     44     # if autolimit is 1, we only want to fetch one row

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sql\run\resultset.py:466, in ResultSet._init_table(self)
    463 pretty = CustomPrettyTable(self.field_names)
    465 if isinstance(self._config.style, str):
--> 466     _style = prettytable.__dict__[self._config.style.upper()]
    467     pretty.set_style(_style)
    469 return pretty

KeyError: 'DEFAULT'

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you
I've attempted following the traceback through the .py files in the dependencies but I can't work out the issues

Point of clarification in regards to the first sentence of text: %%sql is a cell magic and not a line magic. It is sort of referenced here where that syntax like you are trying to use is displayed in an old notebook. As to your issue... Maybe pertinent is here? Did you try running a cell like %config SqlMagic.style = '_DEPRECATED_DEFAULT' before the cell magic one in your post? ...

  Less likely, but worth a try of above doesn't help: try leaving sqlite:// off entirely following %%sql since you made a connection already with the previous cell %sql sqlite:///dataProgramming.db , I presume. Just have %%sql as the first line of that cell.

Thank you @Wayne, %config SqlMagic.style = '_DEPRECATED_DEFAULT'  resolved the issue. I'm new to sqlite so I really appreciate the github resource you've provided, it will be very helpful

This issue reported here looks to be the same with very related pointers to similar code in the last parts and the same error.
Following the advice given there:
Try running a cell like %config SqlMagic.style = '_DEPRECATED_DEFAULT' before running the cell magic one in your post.
